# Trouble Configuring GitHub OAuth redirectUrl Flutter

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, github-oauth

I'm working on a Flutter project and using the flutter_web_auth_2 package for OAuth2 authentication. I believe I'm encountering an issue with the redirect URL, as when it's supposed to redirect back to my app, I get the error message 'Safari cannot open the page because the server cannot be found.' I've added the scheme to my Info.plist file, but I'm struggling to understand where the problem might be originating. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue?

```
void githubAuth({required VoidCallback callback}) async {
  LocalSecureStorage storage = LocalSecureStorage();
  final String? githubClientId = dotenv.env['GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'];

  final url = Uri.https('github.com', '/login/oauth/authorize', {
    'client_id': githubClientId,
    'redirect_uri': "area.apps:/",
    'scope': 'user:email repo read:user project notifications',
  });

  final result = await FlutterWebAuth2.authenticate(
    url: url.toString(),
    callbackUrlScheme: "area.apps",
  );
}
```

Info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Src</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>src</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                <string>Editor</string>
                <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                <array>
                    <string>area.apps</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

[image: Github App]

[image: server cannot open the page issu]